# IC power consumption under 50% vs 100% busload

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, communication, bus, power-consumption

Is the dynamic power consumption difference significant for a uC,
 if it has to raise its activity on the chosen bus protocol from, lets say **50%** to **100%**?

I look in overall to the uC+CommController+Transceiver consumption.

Is this a mostly a general rule, or there are exceptions?

**Post edit:**

For an exemplary calculation, I would say the following setup:

- Infineon Tricore TX family MCU (tx29)
- TJA 1081B Flexray Transceiver **OR** TJA 1145 CAN FD transceiver
- 100-120 ohm impedance ensured in physical layer

Comment: Wouldn't that depend how much of the bus protocol circuitry makes up the MCU? And how computationally intensive it is?

Comment: Plus things like drive power and terminations.

Comment: Not only is this MCU dependent (as noted) but also implementation dependent including the chosen drive strength of the output pins as an example.

Comment: What's a "chosen bus protocol"? CAN?

Comment: I completed the question with specifics, but being generally implementation dependent (the significance of difference), I half obtained my response :)